# Is there a way to tell what line of code generates log output without using breakpoints and stepping in Xcode (iOS)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have the following log outputs in Xcode:

```
2013-05-20 17:23:19.901 MyApp[2408:303] invalid pixel format
2013-05-20 17:23:19.901 MyApp[2408:303] invalid context
```

The problem is I don't know what line of code is generating these errors. I've tried walking through but it's extremely tedious considering the complexity of this part of my app. Is there a quick and simple way to track down the line of code that is outputting these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do what you are asking. Simply add the following to your prefix header `YourAppName-Prefix.pch`.

```
#define NSLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);
```

That will override NSLog with a custom NSLog that will print like this:

```
2013-05-20 21:11:10.407 YourAppName[46526:c07] -[JFDepthView initWithGestureRecognizer:] [Line 81] JFDepthView Initialized!
```

It should also work for 3rd party libraries you've added to your project.

Comment: For me, adding this macro causes the build error [Expected ')' to match this '('](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NX6R4.png) in line 422 of NSObjCRuntime.h, where the `NSLog` function is declared. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

From "C" documentation, Standard Predefined Macros - The C Preprocessor:

`__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are useful in generating an error message

```
NSLog(@"Line: %d", __LINE__);
```

Comment: I'm not the one outputting the logs above with NSLog()... it's a generated error by the compiler/Xcode when the app is running. I need to know where it's generated.

Comment: @EthanAllen Neither Xcode or the compiler are outputting those messages. They would be generated by whatever library or framework they are coming from.

Comment: OK, that makes sense, but how do I know which library? And what line of code called into it? I'm only calling into Apple libraries.

Comment: @Ethan, have you tried symbolic breakpoints? I don't know whether it would work because I've never tried it, but its what I would look into.

Comment: @HM If breakpoints were not ruled put a symbolic breakpoint with a condition should work well.